# How to delete a database field named as a reserved word?

Tags: 7, database

I want to drop a field from db table which is named as read.
I tried like;

```
db_drop_field('my_table', 'read');
db_drop_field('my_table', '`read`');
db_drop_field('my_table', `read`);
```

None of these work.

Comment: this should work: db_drop_field('my_table', 'read');

Comment: It does not work. I think because of mysql reserved word. When i tried other fields except 'read', they work.

Comment: Check my answer :-)

Comment: And as I see that you're new here, take 2 minutes to read the tour at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run a custom query:

```
db_query('ALTER TABLE my_table DROP COLUMN `read`');
```

The API functions don't cover every possible edge case, and dropping fields named as reserved words happens to be one of them.

When that fails, executing a standard SQL query is the best option.

Comment: Was just about to suggest using a mysql client to do that work - sometimes these things cannot be done from code.

Comment: If you can do it from any other client, you can do it from PHP @Kevin - they're using the same protocols under the hood

Answer (score 0):

[Read is a reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html), but your problem has an easy solution (I test it and works)

Change your field name to **reading**

And then use:

```
db_drop_field('your_table', 'reading');
```